# Can TypeScript import a folder of Json for convenience?

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, babeljs

Say I have a folder of Json like this

```
myFolder

- lang1.json
- lang2.json
- ...
- lang99.json
- lang100.json
```

If I want to use these in Js with convenience, I can create a `index.js` and import them all

```js
export { default as lang1 } from './myFolder/lang1.json'
export { default as lang2 } from './myFolder/lang2.json'
...
```

Later on, I can just import them from `index.js`

```js
import { lang1, lang2 } from './index.js'
```

Now, I want to get rid of those `export { default as lang1 }` things becuase I have to type a lot of things.

I can easily do this with [babel-plugin-codegen](https://github.com/kentcdodds/babel-plugin-codegen) to generate those code for me, but now TypeScript's typing won't work because TypeScript doesn't know I am generating code at build time.

Is there any better way to do this in TypeScript?

Comment: If you'll pardon the question: _why_ do you 100 .json files? What are these things for? Because the answer to that question is almost to lead to people being able to recommend a better way to do whatever it is you're doing right now.

Comment: It's for multi-language application, the application is quite big.

Comment: Okay, but are they required up front, or only when they need to actually be read out? Because if you're running in, say, ja-JP then it makes very little sense to also load 99 other languages that are not going to get used. Effectively: why not load them on demand using a filename that is strongly tied to the language?